# Authentication options in Smart TV browsers

Tags: authentication, browser, smart-tv

I am about to implement a reception screen view of some data my product holds. This data is not extremely sensitive, but enough so that my customers do not want it just out there on the internet for all to see.

The concept is a smart tv with a built in web browser that displays a webpage hosted by my application. My application requires authentication for all other interaction, but the smart tv does not support authentication. So I would like to secure the page somehow, so it isn't just available for all to see.

The only options I see are:

1. Security by obscurity. I would really like to avoid this one.
2. IP Whitelisting. This I could do, but not all my clients have a static IP.
3. Enter credentials on screen. This is not really feasible and the credentials are lost on reboot. So we cannot do this.

Are there other options I just don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that the best option is the OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Flow.

The gives the user an experience like the one used when setting up Google Chromecast or AppleTV.

https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/device-authorization-flow

Answer (score 0):

For límited input devices like TVs where is not easy enter credentials there are some Open Source options like CPA (developed by EBU for Hbbtv Use Cases) than can work for you and you can control the e2e

[CPA](https://tech.ebu.ch/groups/CPA)

[Reference Implementation](https://tech.ebu.ch/code)

The autenticacion token can be stored into your SmartTV app until its expiration or client's logout, etc.

There is also